# How to check which database read node is used for the current request in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, database, postgresql

How can I check on page load which read node is used from the defined ones in `config/database.php` for the request?

```
            'read' => [
                'host' => [
                    env('DB_HOST_READ_1'),
                    env('DB_HOST_READ_2')
                ]
            ],
            'write' => [
                'host' => env('DB_HOST_WRITE')
            ],
```

I tried with

```
public function test(User $user) {
    dd($user->getConnection());
}
```

but this isn't giving me the information I'm looking for.

**PostgreSQL**

Comment: Why do you need this information? The node should be defined automatically depending on the final query (read/write).

Comment: I want to make sure it's working and it's actually choosing different databases if you understand me. I'll just keep refreshing the page and watch if the host is changing.

Comment: Ah, I understand. Probably, you could try to listen query events: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database#listening-for-query-events

Check the query object, probably it has the connection information as well

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will help you

https://laravel.com/api/9.x/Illuminate/Database/Connection.html#method_getConfig

```
  public function test(User $user) {
    dd($user->getConnection()->getConfig()); // get connection detail
}
```